# Droid x , Linearlayout background image isn't showing ?

Tags: android, background, android-linearlayout

I have developed many android apps and I always use android:background = "@/drawable/imagename" and it always worked.
Now I'm testing on three devices (Galaxy s , droid x and droid 2 ) and the emulator . 
All the emulators display the background , and the galaxy . but non of the droids !.

I tried both PNG and JPG images with no luck . what do you think ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the resolution of the screens, the image files are pulled from different places. I've had similar issues.
Try to move the file into drawable-hdpi or drawable-mdpi.

Comment: The image was too large for mobiles (2000*1700) even though some devices managed to resize it , some didn't . so I resized it manually and everything is ok now